# Does provisioning have a place in the Drupal world?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, devops

My team is relatively new to Drupal. One thing we have struggled to understand is how to work with it from a DevOps point of view. I realize this is too large a subject for one question so I have a more specific question that gets at the heart of the matter.

How does one provision a Drupal instance? By "provision", I mean create a provisioning script that builds my CMS (we're only using Drupal for that purpose) starting with a clean virtual machine with only OS and web server. The script would install and configure Drupal and its modules and connect to an existing database containing my content. Or perhaps I can even have it add my content to Drupal instance with an empty database. I'm just not sure what makes sense.

What I am trying to avoid is the uncertainty and non-reproducability that comes with doing everything interactively via Drupal's UI. I realize that Drupal has lots of techniques for exporting various things but there doesn't appear to be any coherent overall picture. Every bit of advice is of the form, "If you want to do (some specific thing), this is how you might do it." Or, even worse, "This worked for me." Neither of these things gives me much confidence or, more importantly, gives decent "best practices" advice that tells us what Drupal's designers intended.

There are some Drupal "best practices" articles but they don't go much beyond advice such as, "Do a backup before changing anything." I need more useful advice.

Comment: Are you provisioning for a cohesive local development environment, or are you looking to do this for a production based model?

Comment: This is one of the main reasons I've ditched Drupal. "I got it working in dev, let's hope I can remember all the steps for prod".

Comment: I would want to use my provisioning script for BOTH purposes. It would record all the steps needed to install and configure the software components that make up my CMS. This way, if I change a module or its configuration in the script, I can just rerun the script and know that I have a reproducible installation. My desired workflow is I make changes to the provisioning script, test it out by using it to build a private instance. If it passes the tests, I use it to create the production instance and probably run the tests again just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Drupal 7 the Features module allow configuration export to code. Then on deployment, a single command (executable from CLI using Drush) can be used to sync. the in-database configuration from the code.

The features is now native in Drupal 8 and is called configuration management.

Comment: I've seen that but I'm having trouble understanding what it means to export configuration to code. What kind of code? Sorry but Drupal seems to use a foreign language all its own. I suppose if this "code" is just a text file that some Drush command takes as input then I don't care what format it is in. On the other hand, if I am going to edit that code to change some setting then I do need to know. Finally, I don't see how all this fits into any kind of big picture. What you describe sounds like a small part of a some kind of provisioning process but what's the rest of it look like?

Comment: Also, the Feature module seems to provide this export one item at a time and forces one to select what to dump. How do I dump ALL configuration to code?

Comment: You use Drupal 8 for that (dumping ALL config to disk so that you can migrate it to a new env). Features is designed to export individual components and bundle them all up into a module. Dumping everything to code is not always a great idea. Just dump what you care about migrating from site to site.

Comment: There is no way to export "all configuration" to code with Features, because it wasn't designed for the purpose of configuration management. It is however possible to use it for this task, and many does. See http://dcycleproject.org/ for discussion on this.
You can however do it in Drupal 8 using its configuration management.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a Database driven application and in that case snapshot of db has to be released as well.
Pre-deployment step would be to create db and dump the snapshot.
You can run post-deployment scripts to configure environment specific configuration.